# Android DialogFragment layout, Odd extra whitespace

Tags: android, layout, dialogfragment

So after making a `dialogfragment` for a simple "have user choose" popup, I loaded it up and saw some odd extra whitespace in the layout, I'm unsure what's causing it and I've been wracking my brain trying to figure it out. I've modified the xml slightly to better show the behavior, the only difference is I've changed the widths of the 3 vertical sections from "match_parent" to "wrap_content" so I can use a border to show the actual size of the whitespace. Here is a picture showing the problem:

[image: the problem]

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pictureSourceMainTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Where would you like to choose\nyour image from?"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pictureSourceIVLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceCancelIV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceGalleryIV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceCameraIV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pictureSourceTVLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceCancelTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceGalleryTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Gallery" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pictureSourceCameraTV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/tvborder"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Camera" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So my question is: What can I do to remove this extra whitespace? Is my xml layout missing something? I could manually set the size of the width every time but I'd much rather the window itself actually "wrap_content"

EDIT: It turns out the resizing is being caused by the title, is there a way to shrink the title down to the proper size?

Comment: Just try looking what is that extra space from the graphical layout tab in xml editor?

Comment: You have `match_parent` for your `width` in your actual `layout` for all of your `View`s including the root `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @user2511882 there's nothing to look at, in the xml editor as well there's nothing there

Comment: @codeMagic: the three objects I changed from "match_parent" to "wrap_content" to demonstrate the whitespace are: "pictureSourceMainTextView, pictureSourceIVLayout, and pictureSourceTVLayout", when reverted back to "match_parent" it fills the extra space, but I'm not wanting that, I'm wanting it to wrap to the size of the content

Comment: So what do you want where the white space is? Also, in your second child `LinearLayout` you should have `android:layout_height="0dp"` because you are using `weight`

Comment: @codeMagic: "I'm wanting it to wrap to the size of the content"

Answer (score 13):

The culprit was the title. Setting:

```
getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in the `oncreateview` in my dialogfragment fixed all size issues, I simply added a new `imageview` to the top and designed my own title in photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Change  `android:layout_width` of `TextView` to `"fill_parent"`.
You can also add `android:gravity="center"` to the outer `LinearLayout`